# SOA data replication and architecture

Tags: postgresql, architecture, nosql, soa

[image: My application back-end architecture]

I want to separate my Sign-on APIs as SSO-service. Cause of the heavy load on them, I just want to load balance this service. The SSO-service just needs USER table from my primary database, So I thought it would be more efficient to replicate USER table into another database for reads and handle the write operations with my primary database(btw writes are infrequent). Then I came up with the architecture in Image.
here are my questions:
1: Can the architecture be better somehow?
2: Should I use NoSQL databases for reading operations(maybe Redis)? If yes, How do handle these scenarios with it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.